# On understanding correlation of bind and inheritance

Tags: javascript

Today I was reading the MDN documentation on [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). Under the section [Bound functions used as constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Bound_functions_used_as_constructors) there is an example that I cannot quite understand.

I ran the following piece of code both in Node.js (v.4.4.5) and Google Chrome ( v58.0.3029.81)

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.toString = function() { 
  return this.x + ',' + this.y; 
};

var p = new Point(1, 2);
p.toString(); // '1,2'

var emptyObj = {};
var YAxisPoint = Point.bind(emptyObj, 1/*x*/);

var axisPoint = new YAxisPoint(5);
console.log(axisPoint.toString()); // '1,5'

console.log(axisPoint instanceof Point); // true
console.log(axisPoint instanceof YAxisPoint); // true
console.log(new Point(17, 42) instanceof YAxisPoint); // true
```

I can clearly see why `axisPoint` is an instance of both `Point` and `YAxisPoint`. But how in the world can `new Point(17,42)` be an instance of `YAxisPoint`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how in the world can `new Point(17,42)` be an instance of `YAxisPoint`?

Because `instanceof` works special with bound functions (those created from `.bind()` calls). Usually it would check whether the object inherits from the constructors `.prototype`, but bound functions don't have a `.prototype`. Instead, when you use `instanceof` on a bound function, it checks whether the object is an instance of the target function (that `bind()` was called upon). So

```
… instanceof YAxisPoint
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
… instanceof Point
```

You can check this in the specs ([ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.3), [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance)).