# Using "hard bind function" and "instanceof" operator

Tags: javascript, prototype, bind

I'm currently learning JavaScript by following the series "You don't know JS".

In the section "this & object prototype, when discussing using `instanceof` operator to determine prototype linkage between different objects, the author stated

> Note: If you use the built-in .bind(..) utility to make a hard-bound
>   function, the function created will not have a .prototype property.
>   Using instanceof with such a function transparently substitutes the
>   .prototype of the target function that the hard-bound function was
>   created from.

I understand how `.bind()` and hard-bound function works, and I have a okay understanding of how `.prototype` property works. The thing that confuses me is the last sentence

> Using instanceof with such a function transparently substitutes the
>   .prototype of the target function that the hard-bound function was
>   created from.

What does the last sentence actually mean?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43821537/1048572) answer your question?

Comment: @Bergi yes it does!! Thank you so much for pointing it out!!